# Positioning nested ul

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

I have a nested ul (menu) and want to position the nested menu *directly beneath* the containing menu, starting on the *same horizontal position* as the outer menu.

[See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zdkb5/)

In this example the nested menu is positioned too far to the left and a little too high (it should start vertically where the containing menu ends).

I might use `left: 0px;` as showed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zdkb5/1/) to fix the horizontal position, but that still doesn't fix the vertical position.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `top:40px;` to fix the vertical position

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/zdkb5/2/

Comment: But what if the height of the outer menu is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with:

`margin-top:10px;` to the `#menu > ul > li > ul` class

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/zdkb5/5/)**

The height of the outer container is irrelevant.

Comment: Nice, but now I want to use `position: relative` on the inner menu, to make the submenu take up space in the complete flow of the page. This breaks it though: http://jsfiddle.net/zdkb5/9/

Comment: You want it to actually take up page space rather than hover over it?